# Data chunks in node-curl (node.js)

Tags: node.js

I am using node-curl as a HTTPS client to make requests to resources on the web and the code runs on a machine behind a proxy facing the internet.

The code I am using to co:

```
var curl = require('node-curl');
//Call the curl function. Make a curl call to the url in the first argument.
//Make a mental note that the callback to be invoked when the call is complete 
//the 2nd argument. Then go ahead.
curl('https://encrypted.google.com/', {}, function(err) {
    //I have no idea about the difference between console.info and console.log.
    console.info(this.body);
});
//This will get printed immediately.
console.log('Got here');
```

node-curl detects the proxy settings from the environment and gives back the expected results.

The challenge is: the callback gets fired after the entire https-response gets downloaded, and as far as I can tell there are no parallels for the ['data' and 'end' events](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_data_1) from the http(s) modules.

Further, after going through the source code, I found that indeed the node-curl library receives the data in chunks: reference line 58 in https://github.com/jiangmiao/node-curl/blob/master/lib/CurlBuilder.js . It seems that no events are emitted presently in this case.

I need to forward the possibly-sizable-response back to the another computer on my LAN for processing, so this is a clear concern for me.

Is using node-curl recommended for this purpose in node?

If yes, how can I handle this?

If no, then what would be a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the wonderful [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module, at least if the proxy settings are no more advanced than what it supports. Just read the proxy settings from the environment yourself:

```
var request = require('request'),
    proxy = request.defaults({proxy: process.env.HTTP_PROXY});

proxy.get('https://encrypted.google.com/').pipe(somewhere);
```

Or if you don't want to `pipe` it:

```
var req = proxy.get({uri: 'https://encrypted.google.com/', encoding: 'utf8'});

req.on('data', console.log);
req.on('end', function() { console.log('end') });
```

Above, I also pass the `encoding` I expect in the response. You could also specify that in the defaults (the call to `request.defaults()` above), or you could leave it in which case you will get `Buffer`s in the `data` event handler.

If all you want to do is to send it to another URL, request is perfect for that:

```
proxy.get('https://encrypted.google.com/').pipe(request.put(SOME_URL));
```

Or if you'd rather `POST` it:

```
proxy.get('https://encrypted.google.com/').pipe(request.post(SOME_URL));
```

Or, if you want to proxy the request to the destination server as well:

```
proxy.get('https://encrypted.google.com/').pipe(proxy.post(SOME_URL));
```

Comment: I thank you for your timely and excellently worded answer. I will get back to you regarding whether indeed I finally use this. But this is superb.

Comment: Thank you for saying that -- it's literally what makes me, and (I think) all of StackOverflow tick! If you don't use it, at least now you know about the request module, which I find supremely useful.